# random testing sqlite

Tags: testing, random, sqlite

For one of my testing project, I am working on sqlite testing. I see that they have have a regression test suite. Is it an open source test suite I can use? I am either planning to use a test suite available or design a test suite..My aim is to design a huge number of tests (so using random values adn assigning them is the best call)
Any help and views wil be appreciated:-)

Answer (score 1):

Saying they have a regression test suite is a little bit of an understatement.  The SQLite engine itself has 73,000 lines of code.  The test suite has 91,378,600 lines of test code.  Besides that, the library is C and tests are TCL, so a lot more bang for your buck in each line of test code.

You can read about SQLite's regression test suite here:

http://www.sqlite.org/testing.html

And you can browse and download the source from the public repository (requires anonymous login):

http://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/dir?name=test